# How to create such toggle buttons in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I did not find the answer in Google, so I am writing here. In general, I need to make a toggle button that looks like this (attached a photo), with exactly this shape, with changing the color of the icon and it should have the functionality of a regular togglebutton, maybe someone knows the manuals? Thanks everyone!
[First photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsToR.png)  [Second photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpxeE.png)

Comment: Based on state replace images

Comment: Change the image resource if(Your state =true) setImage ON state image else setImage OFF state image

Comment: @GobuCSG I understand, but the point is different, I need to make exactly the style of togglebutton, which will give the toggle just such a design, how to change the color of the icons, I understand, I need to understand exactly how to make such an arrangement of buttons, text, additional text, with the possibility of it editable by the user (that is, they must have a line in the button configuration) and that there is just such a background.